# building CEF binaries to use with CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I built CEF 4147 Release x64 binaries to use with CefSharp/84. I used the steps outlined in the CEF MasterBuildQuickStart Wiki. I noticed it generates DLLs, etc that are the same versions as those that come with CefSharp/84. There are some differences, however. The two DLLs in the swiftshshader folder are much smaller and come with LIB files in my build. When I use CefSharp with my CEF build it doesn't work. CefSharp.core.dll cannot load some dependency.

Does CefSharp require any defines that are not used in MasterBuildQuickStart?

Comment: MasterBuildQuickStart creates a debug build used for development purposes,  not suitable for distribution. The build commands listed under https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration should create you a release build. CefSharp has no special build requirements, official releases use builds from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html

Comment: You might also want to checkout https://github.com/mitchcapper/CefSharpDockerfiles

Comment: MasterBuildQuickStart creates both a Debug build and a Release build, I think. At least, that is what I find in the out folder.

Comment: The guide is for creating a development build.  You need different args for a release build. Have a quick re-read of the first few paragraphs when you get a second.

Comment: I think you are referring to step 8 in MasterBuildQuickStart. It's in that step that a Debug build is created. I am simply replacing "Debug" with "Release" in that step. Isn't that a Release build? If not, then I am confused.

Comment: Even changing debug to release you'll still get a development build. I believe they call it a component build, you get a dll for every component. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration has the arguments for creating an official build which is what you need.

Comment: That's right. If I understand this correctly, a component build has the hundreds of components compiled each as separate DLLs. How to end up with same DLLs at CefSharp was my original question. I think I found the answer to my question. In steps 6 and 7 of MasterBuildQuickStart the batch files define `is_component_build=true`. When I set this to false and re-build branch 4147 I get exactly the same DLLs with identical byte sizes as those that come with CefSharp/84.

Comment: Use `set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true` to ensure you get an official build. As specified in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I am using that too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to re-create the the CEF binaries that come with CefSharp/84 (CEF build 4147) using the instructions in [MasterBuildQuickStart](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md) after making the following changes (in bold).

1. In Step 6:

   set GN_DEFINES=**is_component_build=false is_official_build=true**

   # Use vs2017 or vs2019 as appropriate.

   set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2019 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*

   python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=c:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=c:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build **--branch=4147**
2. In Step 7:

   set GN_DEFINES=**is_component_build=false is_official_build=true**

   # Use vs2017 or vs2019 as appropriate.

   set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2019 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/* call cef_create_projects.bat
3. In Step 8:

   ninja -C out\**Release_GN_x64** cef